# VB.NET Date Comparison Not Returning Correct Results?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, linq, datetime, date

I am pulling a date value from my database:

```
        Dim qfresho = From p In dbConfig.Configs _
                     Where p.Description = "FROD" _
                    Select p.dateValue
        Dim qfreshc = From p In dbConfig.Configs _
                      Where p.Description = "FRCD" _
                      Select p.dateValue
```

Then comparing these date values to the current date:

```
        If qfresho.First.Value >= Date.Now And qfreshc.First.Value <= Date.Now Then
        lblFreshman.Text = "Freshmen are currently eligible to register for a room."
    Else
        Dim frdays As TimeSpan
        frdays = (qfresho.First.Value).Subtract(Now)
        lblFreshman.Text = "Registration will open for freshmen in " & frdays.Days & " days."
    End If
```

But for some reason its always returning the Else condition - even though the values in the database should make the query true. Any ideas? I'm guessing for some reason its not pulling the results as a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date.Now returns a DateTime, so does your database have dates and times or just dates?  If you just want the date, you can use Date.Today.

Comment: This might be part of the problem, but I updated the code to use Date.Today and it still doesn't work. When I look at the various via the debugger I can see it is pulling back values like #3/1/2011# with a type of "Date?" - I'm not sure why it is unsure of this?

Comment: Then I would suggest adding some debugging to see which condition is giving you trouble, so do  Debug.WriteLine(qfresho.First.Value >= Date.Now) and Debug.WriteLine(qfreshc.First.Value <= Date.Now) to see which one is evaluating false.

Comment: About the "Date?" type: this means it's a nullable date. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981315(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Do the dates have time components that could be throwing off the compares?

Comment: There are no time components, thus I am now using Date.Today per John's suggestion above.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just add two debugs before the comparison???

```
    Debug.WriteLine(qfresho.First.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ffff"))
    Debug.WriteLine(qfreshc.First.Value.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.ffff"))
```

That should help.